# Performances problems with back button when I have severals LonglistSelector with Images on WP8

Tags: image, windows-phone, transition, longlistselector

In my windows phone app, I have a Page with 7 pivots items, each pivot contain one listbox, in each listbox I have one image per item (load from web). when I click on one of them, I go to another page.

When I push on back button, the transition between pages is very slow. The problem comes from listbox and probably because of images. I don't know how resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you use thumbnails? Big images can easily fill up the phone memory, are you testing on a device or the emulator?

Comment: Yes I use, I test with my device

Comment: Did you check the images size?

Comment: image have 125x70 resolution, but there are a lot

Comment: How much is a lot? Check out this SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126692/nested-listbox-with-lot-of-images-is-jittering-and-slow-in-wp7

Answer (score 0):

You can set itemssource of your current pivot item to null (listbox in this case). Pivot read its elements on demand, so it's innecesary to have those elements on it.

Remember that mobile platform is limited. So, consider another options rather than ListBox in Windows Phone.

Hope it helps.